# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft].....SQL Server]Invalid column name '0'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to update existing SQL-Data base by using to_sql() Function.....

When I am trying to run the code I find this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1225, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 399, in do_executemany
    super(MSDialect_pyodbc, self).do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 578, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '0'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '1'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '2'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '3'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '4'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '5'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Tooling/20200206/MyDB_Update.py", line 22, in <module>
    new_df.to_sql('MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027', con=mydb, if_exists='append', index=True)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2530, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(self, name, con, schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists,
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 458, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1174, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 686, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 599, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1095, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1225, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 399, in do_executemany
    super(MSDialect_pyodbc, self).do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 578, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '0'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '1'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '2'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '3'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '4'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name '5'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027] ([index], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ((0, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts038831', 50660, 3180, 50660, 898), (1, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts005811', 11063, 3180, 11063, 1091), (2, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts089431', 53462, 3170, 53462, 1111), (3, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts088191', 47274, 3200, 47274, 1108), (4, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts026851', 49386, 3200, 49386, 1145), (5, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts026911', 52128, 3180, 52128, 1054), (6, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts088191', 45101, 3200, 45101, 1106), (7, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts005541', 10970, 3180, 10970, 1090)  ... displaying 10 of 1200 total bound parameter sets ...  (1198, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts005331', 10902, 3170, 10902, 1187), (1199, 'RTWAGB2', 'bts005331', 10902, 3170, 10902, 1187))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

and this is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from MyDB import Add_To_DB
mydb = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://WWX542337CDCD\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')  # name of database
mycursor = mydb.raw_connection().cursor()
myDB = Add_To_DB.mydb
myCursor = Add_To_DB.mycursor
df = pd.read_excel('MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027 - Copy (2).xlsx',sheet_name='GSM Details')
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100000)

print(df)
date=df['Date']
GBSC=df['GBSC']
Site_Name=df['Site Name']
Cell_CI=df['Cell CI']
cell_LAC=df['Cell LAC']
cell_name=df['Cell Name']
cell_index=df['CellIndex']
site_name = df['Site Name']


comp_zip=zip(GBSC,Site_Name,Cell_CI,cell_LAC,cell_name,cell_index)
new_df=pd.DataFrame(comp_zip)
new_df.columns  = new_df.columns.str.replace('\s+','')
new_df.to_sql('MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027', con=mydb, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

DB Part:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Add_To_DB():
    # connect db
    mydb = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://WWX542337CDCD\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
    mycursor = mydb.raw_connection().cursor()

    def insert_into_db(insert_zip, mycursor, mydb):
        sql = "Insert INTO [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027] (GBSC, SiteName, CellCI, CellLAC, CellName, CellIndex) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        val = insert_zip
        for v in val:
            print(v)
```

Note That, there's a difference in Columns name between the Excel file and the database sql... The difference is there's no spaces in SQL Data-Base and there's Spaces in the Excel file

Comment: two possible issues, one your columns are integers, transform them `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)` second, you don't have matching target columns in `MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027` check the columns match _exactly_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Pandas to\_sql determine what dataframe column is placed into what database field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771256/how-does-pandas-to-sql-determine-what-dataframe-column-is-placed-into-what-datab)

Comment: @Datanovice actually I can't understand what that mean :(

Comment: remove `df.columns.astype(str)` that should do the trick

Comment: @Datanovice `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')` same error :(

Comment: Strange, I can't replicate your error, I just tried it in a fresh VM works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO [MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027] ([index], [0], [1], [2], >[3], [4], [5]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
```

You cannot use `0, 1, 2, 3 ...` as your column names.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer but please Could you check my DB part I just post it now :)

Comment: 1.  "if_exists='append' " means when the table 'MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027' has already exists,  the insert sql must use  the  exactly same column in that table.

Comment: 2.  to_sql sentence doesnt use "index_lable",  and  the index name will be used as column name in the insert sql.  and your df's index name is [0, 1, 2...]. which doesnot match  table 'MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027's column.  Thats why it failed

Comment: 3. Two way to correct it.  The first is  rename you df's index name with your table's column name. The second is set "index_lable"  in the to_sql sentence.

Comment: 4.  I am not a english speaker.  If my reply makes you feel impolite or something weired, I am sorry for that .   Hope this can help you .

Answer (score 1):

> Note That, there's a difference in Columns name between the Excel file and the database sql... 
>   The difference is there's no spaces in SQL Data-Base and there's Spaces in the Excel file

That's your issue, your target columns *must* match your target database columns, how else would it know what columns to match?

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771256/how-does-pandas-to-sql-determine-what-dataframe-column-is-placed-into-what-datab) answer for more information.

the solution to your problem could be done in one of two ways,

```
new_df.columns  = new_df.columns.str.replace('\s+','')
```

or you could call your database

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * TOP 1 from MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027",con=mydb)
```

then you can compare both columns by calling `df.columns`

Comment: I tried your code and I find this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`, I'll try again after your update :)

Comment: I just tried this on my own dataset, it works fine. are you sure you called it on `new_df.columns` ?

Comment: what is `df` `print(type(df))`

Comment: it is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Answer (score 0):

I get the error with writing in Python code. If anyone use Python to connect with SQL as I do, the problem will be fixed if you replace `'`  with `"`.

This works:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from names where n like 'AA' ")
```

This doesn't:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from names where n like 'AA' ')
```

Comment: Note that you can also escape the single quotes: `\'AA\'`