# Python 3.7 - How to load dynamic csv to pre existing mysql table irrespective of column order from file python

Tags: python-3.7

I have to load a csv to pre-existing table(with data) in mysql db using python. But the column order is not same as the ones in the table. I cannot modify the csv also. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771256/how-does-pandas-to-sql-determine-what-dataframe-column-is-placed-into-what-datab) the column order is not important, you only need to match the column names.
If you need to change the columns names of the data that you load from the csv, then this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) provides info on how to rename columns.